# Hard Drive error: bad/missing sense data

Tags: hard-drive, error-handling

I recently tried to check the spin down time of my hard drive with the following command:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep level
```

and got the error:

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The drive reads & writes data just fine and mounts on startup as well. I just simply cannot run this command on this drive without errors

What does this mean, and how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi, was your hdd connected through a USB port? In this case, you can take a look [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160476) and verify if a new scan (with the hdd attached to a sata port) gives the same error.

Comment: yes through USB. 3 TB drive but it is not a sata drive. external usb

Comment: Has it others interface than USB? If so, you can try to use another interface to repeat the scan. However, probably the error is due to the USB connection and your drive could actually be ok.

Comment: no it is USB only  - external drive

Comment: The drive reads & writes data just fine and mounts on startup as well. I just simply cannot run this commandm on this drive without errors

Comment: It's quite common for USB-SATA bridge chips/firmwares not to support or pass through all SATA commands that modern drives otherwise do. If your drive works fine otherwise, I would just ignore it…

Comment: But is it the same hdd of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/712629/shutting-down-disks-error)?

Comment: @PieCot yes it is the same drive.

Comment: You could try `sudo hdparm --prefer-ata12 -I /dev/sdb`. Man page says "some USB drive enclosures don't work correctly with 16-byte commands".

Comment: @HåkonA.Hjortland - see output at: https://paste.ubuntu.com/16488293/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

looks like your drive controller doesn't support that method of enquiry, not all usb sata chipsets are created equal. You don't say what model of drive or controller you are using so its hard to offer more advice here.

You could test this by plugging into another usb controller or using a different drive with the same controller or better still direct via SATA.

3TB drives can be too big for some usb2 era controllers so i would recommend getting a reputable usb3 sata bridge instead, it will be much faster as well.

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the tiem to reply, my machine has no available sata ports (theres only 1 on intel nuc).;

Comment: Im getting the same issue on a sas drive, using a sata adapter, connected through a `DELL / LSI SAS 9207-8I HBA PCI-E 3.0 X8 LSI00301`   Should i expect issues from this setup i wonder..

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem with my Seagate backup slim and WD black SCSI drives. And I was using `hdparm` as well. What worked for me is the`sdparm` utility.

Install with

```
sudo apt install sdparm
```

Get all parameters/settings with

```
sudo sdparm -l -a /dev/sdX
```

Here `-a` gets all output fields  and `-l` gets the long output i.e. explanation of the output fields. `/dev/sdX` is the drive in question (similar to `/dev/sda`).

Get the spindown timer and the `STANDBY` flag with:

```
sudo sdparm -l --get SCT /dev/sdX
sudo sdparm -l --get STANDBY /dev/sdX
```

The spindown time `SCT` here is in milliseconds and `STANDBY` flag is the spindown timer on/off (1/0) switch

If your output is similar to:

```
# STANDBY     0  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  1]
# SCT       4294967286  [cha: y, def:18000, sav:18000]
```

This means that your device is not set to spin down.

If you want you can change these settings for the current session with:

```
sudo sdparm -l --set SCT=6000 /dev/sdX
sudo sdparm -l --set STANDBY=1 /dev/sdX
```

These settings will be lost on reboot.

Change permanently with:

```
sudo sdparm -l --save --set SCT=6000 /dev/sdX
sudo sdparm -l --save --set STANDBY=1 /dev/sdX
```

Here I chose 6 seconds (6000 milliseconds) but you can choose according to your requirements.

If for some reason, you cannot save your settings, you can put this in your `/etc/rc.local` to set these on boot:

```
sdparm -l --set SCT=6000 --set STANDBY=1 /dev/sdX
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: THANKS! This worked for me. I have USB 3.0 external Western Digital hard drives.

Comment: Unfortunately, this suggestion doesn't work for me. Xubuntu 18.04. Western Digital 4TB

Answer (score 13):

This problem is usually caused by broken/incorrect USB-SATA bridge implementation and should be visible only with USB connected disk enclosures.

In case of external USB disk, the system needs to talk to the SATA drive inside the enclosure using UAS (USB Attached SCSI) protocol over SAT (SCSI / ATA Translation) to send raw ATA commands (sent by `hdparm` or `smartctl`) over SCSI over USB. The reason this protocol chain so complex is due historical reasons.

Somewhere in the chain USB – UAS – SCSI – SAT – SATA some piece of hardware has incorrect implementation. Usually all of this is done by a single microchip inside the enclosure called USB-SATA bridge and some well known variants are ASM1051, ASM1053 and ASM1153. Of these, the ASM1051 is known to be buggy and UAS should be avoided with any hardware containing this chip. ASM1053 and ASM1153 may or may not work depending on actual firmware inside the chip (the manufacturer is allowed to customize the firmware, the reference implementation does work correctly). For example, many enclosures made by Seagate use ASM1153 with custom firmware and have problems with some ATA commands even if the same chip does work correctly with reference firmware. (For example, some enclosures by Seagate work as long as OS never sends any 12 or 16 bit commands. Linux `usb_storage` supports quirk `t` for this purpose.) The end user usually cannot replace the firmware so if you have a bad chip/firmware your only option is to complain to the manufacturer. In case of Seagate, they "fix" the problem by stating that they officially support Windows and OS X only (and those operating systems do not support configuring SATA devices nor fetching S.M.A.R.T. data over USB so everything is "working"). Seagate is nowdays officially working with Linux community so perhaps their products will actually work in the future.

The only real way to figure out the bridge chip is to dismantle the enclosure and inspect the markings in the actual microchips.

**Update:** "Seagate Backup Plus Hub" enclosures have correctly working USB-SATA bridge and UAS works correctly (Note that this is different product from "Seagate Backup Plus"!) However, due to poor history by Seagate's enclosures, the Linux kernel applies the quirk `t` by default which prevents this enclosure from using all SATA features. You can enable full SATA support including S.M.A.R.T. features with following command:

```
echo "0bc2:ab38:" > /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
```

Note the trailing colon and nothing after that - it disables all built-in quirks for the selected vendor:product. Check your vendor and product ids with `lsusb` if needed.

If your device is buggy enough, you may need to totally disable UAS support. This can be done with the `u` quirk. For example, if I would like to disable UAS support on Seagate Backup Plus Hub, I'd run following as root:

```
echo "0bc2:ab38:u" > /sys/module/usb_storage/parameters/quirks
```

After that, the external disk will use only slower but usually working USB storage device features and things end up working... slowly. If you only need to transfer some big files the difference is not that bad. If you have lots of small files, the difference between having working UAS support may be more than 10x speed difference.

Comment: For additional details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI

Comment: See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1810215/comments/18

Comment: See also: https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/SAT-with-UAS-Linux

Comment: And if you disable the UAS support for a given device, `smartctl` and `hdparm` will not work because you cannot send required commands using the "Universal Serial Bus Mass Storage class bulk-only Transport" (BOT) protocol which is the older protocol that will be used if UAS is not available and that's supported by all USB storage devices.

Answer (score 2):

Additional info for systems/devices for which the above and/or modprobe tweaks have no effect (eg Raspberry Pi 3):

The quirks must be added to the boot parameters.  For RPi 3/Raspbian, the  boot parameters are in the file `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

```
[other command line parameters...] usb_storage.quirks=YOUR_VENDOR_ID:YOUR_DEVICE_ID:QUIRK_FLAGS
```

In my case, I needed to clear the quirks flag for my device, so I added this to `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

`usb_storage.quirks=0bc2:a0a4:`

This solved my issue, hopefully it helps someone else