# External drive spins up when Ubuntu suspends

Tags: hard-drive, suspend, external-hdd, spindown

#### Situation

I've got a WD Element Drive that behaves oddly. It took forever for the Drive to spin down, And I'm not able to set the standby (spindown) timeout for the Drive using [different methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time).

For example using `hdparm` causes `SG_IO` error:

```
$ sudo hdparm -S 25 /dev/sdx

dev/sdx:
 setting standby to 25 (2 minutes + 5 seconds)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  ...
```

It seems that the [Drive's controller doesn't support these methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768373/hard-drive-error-bad-missing-sense-data).

However, strangely I'm able to put the drive into standby mode using `-y` switch:

```
$ sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdx
```

It gives the same `SG_IO` error but drive spins down. And I'm fine with that.

#### Real problem

It seems that suspending Ubuntu, causes an effect similar to unplugging and plugging the drive.

When I want to suspend Ubuntu, say using: `systemctl suspend`:

- If drive is on standby mode, it spins up and never spins down again.
- If it's not on standby mode, then it first spins down, after a second it spins up again and never spins down.

The only way to spin it down is to resume Ubuntu and run `hdparm -y` on the drive manually and if I suspend Ubuntu again, the same thing happens.

#### What I already tried

I tried to run `hdparm -y` on suspend to put the drive on `standby` mode:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/suspend_drive

#!/bin/sh    
case $1 in
  pre)
    hdparm -y /dev/sdc ;;
esac
```

It does not have any effect. And as I already said, while Ubuntu is going to sleep, drive first spins downs for a second anyway, and then it starts working again.

---

#### What I'm looking for...

Is there anyway to troubleshot this problem?

I'm looking for a solution to prevent the drive from spinning up in the first place when the system is going to sleep. And if the drive is already awake, it should go to standby mode with the system.

---

Notes:

- Running Ubuntu 20.04.
- I'm not interested in detaching the drive (or using any method that takes away the power from USB ports, as it has the same result of unplugging the drive).
- or using something like `udiskctl poweroff`.
- Here is another similar question: [Prevent external USB hard drive from spinning up during suspend to RAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312392/prevent-external-usb-hard-drive-from-spinning-up-during-suspend-to-ram)

---

### Updates

- If I use `udisksctl power-off /dev/sdc` to safely remove the drive, suspending the Ubuntu acts like unplugging and re-pluging and I can mount and use the drive again (something that should not happen).
- I was able to set a standby timer for the drive using `sdparm` but it did not solved the issue, after suspending Ubuntu drive spins-up and never spins down, even if the timer is set to a small value like one minute.
- As I encountered different outcomes, I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that I'm only experiencing the problem while the drive is attached to a USB3 port.

  - But USB2 has it's own problems too, for example after resuming Ubuntu drive spins-up.
- I can confirm than I'm also experiencing the same problem in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out that putting the system in sleep mode acts like unplugging and re-plugging the drive, I got suspected that there might be some issues with the USB ports and their power source.

I went through the BIOS and set "Always On USB" to "Enable"; It seems that setting this parameter to Enable has fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When Western Digital devices are returning `SG_IO` errors it generally means that, while `hdparm` will perform *some* of the operations requested, it is not the correct tool for that particular disk. Instead, [the `sdparm` utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/sdparm.8.html) is required.

For some of the USB3.0 WD disks I have around here, these are the settings that were required to have the things remain spun down after a connected notebook was suspended:

```
sudo sdparm --flexible -6 -l --save --set SCT=3000 /dev/sdX
sudo sdparm --flexible -6 -l --save --set STANDBY=1 /dev/sdX
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `/dev/sdX` with the correct device.</sup>

The first command sets the device to spin down after 5 minutes (assuming the drive's `SCT` value is `100ms`). The second command allows the drive to enter standby mode on its own.

You can show all the parameters and settings for your disk with the following command:

```
sudo sdparm --flexible -6 -l -a /dev/sdX
```

Comment: Although I was able to change the standby timer using `--set SCT=3000` but it did not solved the real problem. `STANDBY` was already set to `1` with `SCT` of `18000`. Drive still spins-up when I suspend the system and won't spin-down. What I'm looking for is actually to prevent the drive from spinning up in the first place when system is going to sleep. I also tested it with a `WD My Passport` drive and same thing happens.

Comment: It’s odd that your drives remain active after suspend. Mine, if not running at the time of suspend, will spin up then shut down almost immediately after the platters reach their optimal rotation speed 

Answer (score 0):

## Edit - Try `hd-idle`

There are many reports how `hdparm` doesn't work properly with WD drives.

The utility [hd-idle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hd-idle/) is written for Linux.

Although its "claim to fame" is spinning down external drives after 10 minutes of inactivity, there may be a method of calling it to spin down during a suspend operation.

`hd-idle` has been [forked on GitHub](https://github.com/adelolmo/hd-idle/blob/master/README.md). Options are provided to keep a log file and to spin down on demand.

---

I've posted variations of this same answer many times in **Ask Ubuntu**. This variation comes from the Q&A:

- [How to turn off the USB power to my mouse, when I suspend the notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823318/how-to-turn-off-the-usb-power-to-my-mouse-when-i-suspend-the-notebook/836725#836725)

---

( ... First part of answer is snipped ... )

## Easier solution power off all USB ports

I recently ran into a problem where an unknown port was preventing laptop from suspending. I found this solution (credit in code) which I modified.

Create the file `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd` using `sudo` powers and insert this code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Same result, however it seems while using this script `Power-Off_Retract_Count` is being incremented.

Comment: @Ravexina Hmm, I would think the script would make the drive behave the same as if the USB cable was unplugged. If you unplug the cable (don't do this with dirty buffers), does the drive automatically spin up?

Comment: @Ravexina I found a program called `hd-idle` worth investigating if you haven't done that already. I've updated answer with links.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it seems that the script is not working as expected in my system. I guess it's somehow related to my USB ports as I just found out that I have the same problem in windows too.

Comment: @Ravexina Perhaps there is a diagnostics utility you can run? There is [this one](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=2) from WD but it boots from DOS. Mind you grub can [chain load](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/DOS_002fWindows.html) to DOS.